# bind() on promise error function - javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, bind, angular-promise, angular-http

I found this codesnippet. Can somebody explain the purpose of the `.bind(this)` in this context? Where would we be able to access `this` now? In the resolved promise?

```
get: function(endpoint, params, callback) {
  var cb = callback || angular.noop;
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get(
    endpoint,
    params
  ).
  success(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
    return cb();
  }).
  error(function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
    return cb(err);
  }.bind(this));

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `bind(newContext)` method of the function object is to return a new function with the context `this` as the first parameter passed to `bind()`.

For example:

```
var message = {text: 'I am the context'};

function tryMe() {
  console.log(this);
}

tryMe(); // will print undefined (in strict mode) or global object
tryMe.bind(message)(); // will print '{text: 'I am the context'}'
```

In your example, the idea of using `bind()` is to keep the context `this` of the `get()` method in the error handler:

```
.error(function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
    //now use this.get() for example
    return cb(err);
  }.bind(this));
```

However no methods associate with the new context were called in the handler.

See more details in [Gentle explanation of `this`](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/).